# How to test Vuex module using Mocha and Chai

Tags: vue.js, mocha.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

I'm currently using Nuxt and I would like to do unit testing in my vuex modules.

I'm using vuex modules and here's my index.js

**store/index.js**

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import * as user from "~/store/modules/users";

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {},
    mutations: {},
    modules: {
      user
    }
  });
};

export default createStore;
```

and here's the vuex for users (I made it very simple by mutating the count only but I'm doing api requests here)

**store/modules/user.js**

```
export const state = {
  count: 0
}

export const mutations = {
  INCREMENT(state, user) {
    state.count += 1;
  }
}

export const actions = {
  incrementCount({commit}) {
    commit('INCREMENT');
  }
}

export const getters = {
  count(state) {
    return state.count;
  }
}
```

I would like to use Mocha and Chai, for testing state, actions, mutations, and getters for each vuex modules.

Can anyone give a sample for doing a unit test for this?

Comment: Testing mutations, getters and state are simple since they are just js object and functions. The tough part is testing actions. Checkout this https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/testing.html#testing-actions